# How to add a module into Spyder 2.3.4?

Tags: python, installation, spyder

I've read elsewhere on this forum that to add a module into Spyder, simply open an ipython console and type:

!pip install trading_ig

Unfortunately I get the following error:

Collecting trading-ig
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement trading-ig (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for trading-ig

Help please? (Windows 10, Spyder 2.3.4)

Comment: It seems that pip is not able to connect to the internet. Using `pip install trading_ig` gives exactly the desired result. You should check the proxy settings and connection as well as the firewall settings. Does it work with other packages?

Comment: Awesome. It was the firewall. Thanks very much.